# Get raw pointer from a ruby object (derived from C library)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a library (let's call it A) written in C. This library has function to interact an open source library B (also written in C).,

Now I am working on A's ruby binding using Ruby FFI. B also has a ruby binding, but it is written in ruby extension. In order to hookup with ruby-B, I need to retrieve the raw pointer from the ruby object.

I am very new to ruby extension, and is it possible?

Comment: You should be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve, especially in terms of a concrete example with code. Any C code only sees Ruby objects as pointers anyway, and all C extensions should see the same pointer for the same object.

Comment: This question needs example code to be answerable with a different answer than "in most cases it is possible, yes".